# Suppose G is a group, a, b ∈ G such that |b| = 2 and bab = a^4 .

Tags: group-theory, discrete-mathematics

[image]

I know that answer is (2) |a| divides 15 but I'm not sure how they got the answer, any hints will be helpful thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: $$\begin{align}a^{16} &= (bab)^4\\ &= babbabbabbab \\ &= ba^4 b\\ &= b(bab)b \\ &= a.\end{align}$$